# PhantomJS WebDriver with .pac autoproxy settings?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, phantomjs, http-proxy

Is it possible to use the PhantomJS WebDriver with Selenium and .pac autoproxy settings? Currently I am using the code below.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS,new String[] {"--ssl-protocol=any", "--proxy=na-proxy-url:port","--proxy-auth="+ netID + ":"+ netPassword, "--ignore-ssl-errors=true", "--proxy type=https"});
```

Web traffic is normally directed through our north america proxy, but sometimes an alternate proxy is used. Is there a way to replace na-proxy-url with my_url.pac ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some headache I realized this is not possible with PhantomJS as the WebDriver. See GitHub [Issue 10834](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10834)

It can be done with HtmlUnit, but that comes with the trade-offs of using HtmlUnit. (Unfortunately doesn't load the page I'm scraping properly) Sample code below for HtmlUnitDriver in Java.

```
        HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(){
        protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client){
            DefaultCredentialsProvider creds = new DefaultCredentialsProvider();

            creds.addCredentials("username", "password");
            client.setCredentialsProvider(creds);
            return client;
        }
        };
        driver.setAutoProxy("http://my_url.pac");
```